# Event handling across dialogs in azure

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am building a chatbot with **Azure Function bot**. The question here is how can I make a dialog flow wait for a API call to complete (which was fired in another dialog flow).

For Example:

- **Greeting Dialog flow** triggers **GetUserProfile** API call
- ProductSuggestion Dialog flow has to wait from GetUserProfile to complete and use the response to provide suggestion.

I know there backchannel mechanism between client and server.

But is there way to build a event listener between dialogs with in the server?

Comment: Can you confirm it is ok now? @GhostCat

Comment: I modified it. Can you check? @GhostCat

Comment: Voted for-reopen. Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: I've also voted to reopen.  Maybe if you add some code that you've tried, it might help.  (Azure functions aren't normally a good solution for bots.  imo, there are few actual use cases for an azure functions bot, vs a web app bot.)

Comment: supported to reopen this post, hoping to see some code snippet about your question.